# IO Completion Ports and OVERLAPPED management

Tags: c++, winapi, iocp

How win32 manages instances of OVERLAPPED struct in context of two functions:

```
GetQueuedCompletionStatus
PostQueuedCompletionStatus
```

1. When I call GetQueuedCompletionStatus does win32 free instance of OVERLAPPED struct or I must do it by my self?
2. When I send data with PostQueuedCompletionStatus does win32 copy it to internal structs? When I must free memory of sent data?
3. Where I could find some picture with scheme of processing of OVERLAPPED data between GetQueuedCompletionStatus, PostQueuedCompletionStatus and IOCP queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OVERLAPPED` structure must exist from when a successful I/O operation (or manual [PostQueuedCompletionStatus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) executes until the `OVERLAPPED` emerges from a call to [GetQueuedCompletionStatus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You are responsible for the lifetime of the structure.

You'll see from the MSDN docs that `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` actually takes "a pointer to a variable that receives the address of the `OVERLAPPED` structure that was specified when the completed I/O operation was started.". What you actually get out of that call is a pointer to the original `OVERLAPPED` that you passed when you made the `PostQueuedCompletionStatus()` call (or initiated an overlapped I/O operation).

This is all actually very useful as the "normal" way to use the `OVERLAPPED` structure is to place it inside a larger structure which holds all of the 'per operation' information that you might need - so it's the ideal way to navigate directly from the limited information that you're given when you call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to, for example, the data buffer that you used in your overlapped read call...

I find the best way to deal with `OVERLAPPED` structures is to a) embed them in the buffer you're using for read/write b) reference count them and c) return them to a pool for reuse when the ref count drops to 0.

I have some source code that you could download ([here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html)) which may make this a little easier to understand (it's a full IOCP server example so it's a little complex, but it works and shows how these things can be used).

Comment: Len please tell me if call of PostQueuedCompletionStatus() was made by OS, not by me, then must I free recieved data after GetQueuedCompletionStatus() or in this case I am not the owner of it? By call of OS I mean for example can be message that file changed.

Comment: All `OVERLAPPED` structures that come out of a call to GetQueuedCompletionStatus() were originally owned by you at some point.    You will have called a function, such as `WSARecv()` or `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` and passed in the `OVERLAPPED`. There are NO situations (as far as I know) where you can call an API which causes a completion to occur using an `OVERLAPPED` that was not originally supplied by you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should pass a the address of a `OVERLAPPED *` to  `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`. This gets filled in with the value passed to `PostQueuedCompletionStatus`.
2. You should not free this data in the `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` context. It should be done by the context using `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`. (Assuming it was allocated dynamically in the first place - there is no requirement that it is a dynamically allocated structure, it could be taken out of a fixed pool, or be allocated on the stack of a function that doesn't return until it has been signalled that the operation is complete).
3. I'm not sure there is such a picture.

Comment: Mats thank you! As I understood you, by default case I must free only my own data (which I sent by PostQueuedCompletionStatus) and only after GetQueuedCompletionStatus?